# Non supported character set (add orai18n.jar in your classpath)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I am successfully connecting to a Oracle 11g database using objdc8 version 18.3.0.0. When I try to upgrade ojdbc to version 19.3.0.0 I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Non supported character set (add orai18n.jar in your classpath): WE8PC850
```

Adding orai18n to the classpath solves the issue, but I don't understand why I need it for ojdbc 19.3.0.0 when it worked perfectly fine without it for ojdbc 18.3.0.0. Has there been some non backwards compatible change that now requires it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to 19c, the JDBC-thin driver was using a partial implementation of the conversion table for WE8PC850. Starting in 19c it, more correctly, mandates the full conversion table which is included in orai18n.jar. The same thing applies to other character sets that are binary supersets of US7ASCII.